# Dynamic state in Flutter widget

Tags: flutter

I have a logic/conceptual problem that I don't know how to solve.

From API I get an array of objects with dynamic length:

```json
data = [{price: 10, label: 'a'}, {price: 2, label: 'd'}, {price: 5, label: 'b'}]
```

Each of this data corresponds (in UI) to a quantity selector so something like this:

```
a: - 0 + (price: 10)
d: - 0 + (price: 2)
b: - 0 + (price: 5)
```

And then I need to compute the total price.

User can increase and decrease the quantity of each item. For example the app could be in these states:

```
a: - 1 + (price: 10)
d: - 1 + (price: 2)
b: - 0 + (price: 5)
total: 12

a: - 2 + (price: 10)
d: - 1 + (price: 2)
b: - 3 + (price: 5)
total: 37

a: - 0 + (price: 10)
d: - 4 + (price: 2)
b: - 0 + (price: 5)
total: 8

...
```

The problem here is that I don't know how to structure the Widget state.

I created this widget:

```dart
class QuantityUI extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuantityUI({
    Key? key,
    required this.name,
    required this.price,
    required this.counter,
    required this.add,
    required this.remove,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String name;
  final double price;
  final int counter;
  final VoidCallback add;
  final VoidCallback remove;

  @override
  _QuantityUI createState() => _QuantityUI();
}

class _QuantityUI extends State<QuantityUI> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.remove), onPressed: widget.counter == 0 ? null : widget.remove),
        Text(widget.counter.toString()),
        IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: widget.add),
        Text(widget.name.capitalize()),
        Text('${widget.price}€')
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and I use it in the parent widget this way:

```dart
Column(
  children: data.map((Datum d) {
    return QuantityUI(
      name: d.label,
      price: d.price,
      counter: priceCounter, // <-- this should be a variable in my state
      add: () => setState(() => priceCounter++),
      remove: () => setState(() => priceCounter--),
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

This should be dynamic. How can I create `n` variables in the state, one for each `data` item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `counter` for each of your data items and change that `counter` on `add` and `remove` callbacks.
Here is the working solution:

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  late List data = [
      {"price": 10, "label": 'a'},
      {"price": 2, "label": 'd'},
      {"price": 5, "label": 'b'}
    ];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    data = data.map((e) {
      e['counter'] = 0;
      return e;
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: data.map((d) {
          return QuantityUI(
            name: d["label"] as String,
            price: (d["price"] as int).toDouble(),
            counter: (d["counter"]) as int,
            add: () => setState(() => d["counter"]++),
            remove: () => setState(() => d["counter"]--),
          );
        }).toList(),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I think the counter state should be in the parent widgte because is inside the parent widget that I compute the total price

Comment: I completely forgot about your total price calculation. Yeah, so you can change `data` and for each of the items add new parameter `counter`.

Comment: can you update the code? I think I didn't understand what you mean, sorry

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer now.